# How to improve logging information of a deployed meteor application

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I have this situation in which my deployed meteor application doesn't really work as expected. I have no issues in my development environment. I was wondering if it is possible to enable something so that the meteor application gets very verbose with it logging to the console. For example, I'm interested in which resources are requested and if possible also some information about socket requests (Now I get pending socket requests). Any suggestions ?

Comment: Have you considered using Kadira instead ? https://kadira.io/

Comment: As far as I know Kadira is about performance